# Boot ubuntu from external SSD closure

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I had an old laptop with [this](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B078WQT6S6/ref=sr_1_1?hvadid=194633365144&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9044673&hvnetw=g&hvpos=1t1&hvqmt=e&hvrand=15650804963250418538&hvtargid=kwd-474242643797&keywords=evo%20860%20500gb&qid=1573387009&sr=8-1) SSD, and had installed a ubuntu on it (but the grub boot loader was installed on another drive).

Now this old laptop is broken, but I want to make use of my ubuntu on that SSD. I have found [this](https://www.amazon.de/Inateck-festplatten-Werkzeuglose-Installation-Tool-free/dp/B00IJNDBM4/ref=sr_1_3?adgrpid=72098915420&hvadid=353747969711&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9044671&hvnetw=g&hvpos=1t1&hvqmt=b&hvrand=15652402037120332652&hvtargid=kwd-300278951011&hydadcr=1604_1721124&keywords=usb%203%20geh%C3%A4use%202%205&qid=1573313626&sr=8-3) closure to put my SSD on it and connect it to my new laptop with USB 3.

However, I have these questions:

1. Is it possible to boot my ubuntu this way? (if yes, how?)
2. The grub boot loader is left in my old broken laptop, how to boot my ubuntu then?
3. Is this approach going to cause hardware damages to my new laptop? (considering plugging and unplugging of the closure)
4. Am I going to put pressure on my motherboard, causing it to fail or damage?
5. Can I have exactly the same speed of running my ubuntu with this approach, compared to my old laptop where the SSD was connected using SATA 3 ?

[This](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/VivoBook-Pro-N552VW/specifications/) is my old broken laptop. 
[This](https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/hp+pavilion+15+cx0112ng+620772) is my new laptop.

Current situation in my new laptop (has 1TB HDD and 256G SSD):

- Windows 10 installed on the HDD drive.
- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS installed on SSD drive (don't confused with my old ubuntu in my old SSD, this is another ubuntu)
- I can boot both windows and ubuntu with grub bootloader

Comment: Generally it should work. You have to either connect it while booting from the other Ubuntu system and run `sudo update-grub', which should give you a menuentry for Ubuntu from the old laptop. Windows 10 indicates that you boot in UEFI mode, which makes things complicated, if you want to boot directly from the old system, but it is definitely possible. I use such methods, and I don't think it will damage the hardware. *I notice that both computers have nvidia graphics. If they use the same or very similar graphics drivers, fine, otherwise you may need to uninstall/upgrade the graphics driver*.

Comment: When you get the SSD working, try a manual trim to see if it is supported over USB. trim works over eSATA, but not necessarily over USB.